# Importing kernel32 functions for allocating virtual memory in C#?

Tags: c#, dll-injection

I have several DLL files that are on my hard disk. A process on my server contains important file data that I want to log by allocating virtual memory inside the process. I don't have the source code of that process, so I need to reside to more extreem measures. I want it to start the DLL main function. The allocation of memory externally needs to be written in C# due to the fact I want to use it with WPF.

How can you excute your own source code in another process with C#?

Comment: "How can you excute your own source code in another process" That's pretty much exactly what every virus writer would like to know.

Comment: I dll runs on the execution stack like any other function so when you return from the dll all memory is de-allocated except if the dll does an allocate and returns a pointer to the allocated memeory.  allocating in a dll can cause memory leaks unless your c# de-allocates the memory.  Normally the c# code allocates any memory that a dll needs and passes a pointer to the reserved memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to execute your own source code inside a process you need to *virtually allocate memory* for the process and write the path of your DLL inside that memory address you allocated. You will use that DLL path to catapult your dll inside the process using the exported function in *kernel32.dll* `LoadLibraryW`.

---

Each process on the windows platform has a specified memory size dedicated to that process. One of the reasons is for security, a process can’t read or write data to other processes. So in order to be able to write/inject your DLL you need to open a `HANDLE`. You can do this if you import the `OpenProcess` function from the *kernel32.dll*. What this briefly means is that you are using the windows api. Here is how you import the kernel32 DLL in C#

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
  uint dwDesiredAccess, 
  int  bInheritHandle, 
  uint dwProcessId
);
```

> You can find the full documentation of the windows api in the [holy bible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Now, you want to allocate memory to the process that you got a handle from by using the OpenProcess function. Use the VirtualAllocEx function, lets consult the MSDN

> How hath thou allocated thou memory?

```
LPVOID WINAPI VirtualAllocEx(
  _In_     HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_opt_ LPVOID lpAddress,
  _In_     SIZE_T dwSize,
  _In_     DWORD  flAllocationType,
  _In_     DWORD  flProtect
);
```

As we can see it takes 5 parameters. The `HANDLE` object that you collected earlier. An optional parameter that we won’t use. The size of your DLL that you can get if you convert your DLL into an array of bytes. The type of memory allocation, we want to both reserve and commit allocation so use **(0x1000 | 0x2000)** and last the protection for the allocated memory that we will put on write **0x40**.

**STEP 1 Allocate memory ✓**
STEP 2 Write DLL path
STEP 3 use LoadLibraryW

The second step involves using WriteProcessMemory to simply write the dll path in memory. Convert String to array of bytes

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DllPath);
```

Write that array of bytes on the memory you allocated with the windows api function WriteProcessMemory like so.

```
WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, allocatedMemory, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0)
```

**STEP 1 Allocate memory ✓**
**STEP 2 Write DLL path ✓**
STEP 3 use LoadLibraryW

This will be a bit tricky to explain if you have no clue on what *exported functions* are so ill try to give you an abstract understanding.

When creating an application you need to import DLLs that windows provided in order to use some functionalities. For example, you want to send a HTTP request in your application. Even without you knowing you need to load windows *ws2.dll* (windows socket) library. The windows OS provided a handy function that will literally load a library called `LoadLibraryW`. Where can I find this fantastic function? Well no worries child, the kernel32.dll got you covered. All you need to do is find a pointer to the `LoadLibraryW` function. Again, show faith in the MSDN and it shall reward you.

```
FARPROC WINAPI GetProcAddress(
  _In_ HMODULE hModule,
  _In_ LPCSTR  lpProcName
);

HMODULE WINAPI GetModuleHandle(
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpModuleName
);
```

You can read the documentation for more information. Simply put this will find your `LoadLibraryW` function inside *kernel32.dll* since it is an exported function.

```
IntPtr lpLLAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");
```

**STEP 1 Allocate memory ✓**
**STEP 2 Write DLL path ✓**
**STEP 3 use LoadLibraryW ✓**

Start a remotethread inside your process that will simply execute your loadlibrary code

```
CreateRemoteThread(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)null, lpLLAddress, lpAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null)
```

After that simply close the handle to the process and your dll should be ‘*injected*’ inside the process. At any rate if you still haven't figured it out or simply want a class that does it for you here is some source code

### DLLinjector

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace dllInjectExample
{
    public enum DllInjectionResult
    {
        DllNotFound,
        GameProcessNotFound,
        InjectionFailed,
        Success
    }

    public static class DllInjector
    {
        static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress,
            IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

        public static DllInjectionResult Inject(string sProcName, string sDllPath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(sDllPath))
            {
                return DllInjectionResult.DllNotFound;
            }

            uint _procId = 0;

            Process[] _procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < _procs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_procs[i].ProcessName == sProcName)
                {
                    _procId = (uint)_procs[i].Id;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (_procId == 0)
            {
                return DllInjectionResult.GameProcessNotFound;
            }

            if (!bInject(_procId, sDllPath))
            {
                return DllInjectionResult.InjectionFailed;
            }

            return DllInjectionResult.Success;
        }

        private static bool bInject(uint pToBeInjected, string sDllPath)
        {
            IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, pToBeInjected);

            if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)sDllPath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0X40);

            if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDllPath);

            if (WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            IntPtr lpLLAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

            if (lpLLAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (CreateRemoteThread(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, INTPTR_ZERO, lpLLAddress, lpAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null) == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            CloseHandle(hndProc);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Example injecting into csgo since I have no other idea why you would want to inject a dll?

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo").Count() == 0)
            {
                Process Proc = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Application\Steam\Steam.exe");

                Proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
                Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-applaunch 730";
                Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                Proc.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
            }

            while (Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo").Count() == 0)
            {

            }

            var something = DllInjector.Inject("csgo", @"C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\XGame\Debug\XGamedll.dll");
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the great answer fella :D I just need to import all the dlls from kernel with dllimport?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the `*W` functions, instead of the `*A` ones.

Comment: Yes you are right @Joey better to use Unicode. Ill edit my post thanks for the advice!

Comment: You then also need to use Encoding.Unicode instead of ASCII to convert the path. Encoding.ASCII should actually never be correct. And I think you could let marshaling handle that conversion.

Comment: @FrancescoVentura I have learnt so much from this post alone. Thank you so much for taking your time to post this.